# Rotate axis label upside down in R base plot

Tags: r, plot, rotation

I need some help with axis labels in base R plotting, thanks in advance for any guidance!

### What I need:

In `R` base `plot()` I would like to rotate my `axis(3, ...)` label to -90 degrees to get the following output:

[image]

(note that I have rotated the pic outside R)

### Why I need it (big picture):

I am using [`labcurve`](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/Hmisc/html/labcurve.html) for curve annotation and strangely enough for my data the annotation results are visually waay better if applied to the -90 degree rotated graph. After running `labcurve` I can rotate the resulting R-generated PDF back 90 degrees in LaTeX.

### What I have tried:

#### #1

I know that this is governed by the `las` option in [`par`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/par.html) with the following options:

```
0: always parallel to the axis [default],
1: always horizontal,
2: always perpendicular to the axis,
3: always vertical.
```

However, these four options available only cover the two angles 0 and 90 degrees as either of the following:

```
plot(x=c(0,10), y=c(0,1), type='n', xlab='',ylab='', axes=FALSE)
lines(x=c(0,7,7,10), y=c(0,0.33,0.67,1))
axis(2, at=c(0,1), labels=c('',''), las=2)
xlabels <- c('0','10')
axis(3, at=c(0,10), labels=xlabels, las=0)
```

or

```
axis(3, at=c(0,10), labels=xlabels, las=1)
```

[image]

```
axis(3, at=c(0,10), labels=xlabels, las=2)
```

or

```
axis(3, at=c(0,10), labels=xlabels, las=3)
```

[image]

#### #2:

One could think of `str` but according to the doc:

> Note that string/character rotation via argument srt to par does not
>   affect the axis labels.

*Thanks again!*

Comment: You may check [**R FAQ 7.27**](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-create-rotated-axis-labels_003f)

Comment: @Henrik thanks, that works: if you post it as an answer I can accept it. -- btw I changed `par("usr")[3] - 0.25` to `par("usr")[3] - 0.05*(par("usr")[4]-par("usr")[3])` to make it independent from the graph scale. I wonder how one suggests such a change to the R FAQ too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general procedure for creating rotated axis labels is described in [**R FAQ 7.27**](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-create-rotated-axis-labels_003f). Here's a modified example which hopefully suits your needs.

```
# some toy data
x <- c(0, 2, 6, 10)
y <- sample(1:4)

# Increase top margin to make room for rotated labels
par(mar = c(5, 4, 7, 2) + 0.1)

# Create plot without axis or labels
plot(x, y, type = "l", axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")

# positions for tick marks
atx <- range(x)
aty <- range(y)

# x axis without labels
axis(side = 3, at = atx, labels = FALSE)

# y axis without labels
axis(side = 2, at = aty, labels = FALSE)

# add -90 rotated x axis labels
text(x = atx, y = par("usr")[4] + 0.25, srt = -90, adj = 1,
     labels = atx, xpd = TRUE)
```

[image]